# constructor and method used in program didnt understandble

Tags: java

Explain me the code in method and this

```
  class Person {
    public void eat(Apple apple) {
        Apple peeled = apple.getPeeled();
        System.out.println("Yummy");
    }
  }
  class Peeler {
    static Apple peel(Apple apple) {
        // ... remove peel
        return apple; // Peeled
    }
  }
  class Apple {
    Apple getPeeled() {
        return Peeler.peel(this);
    }
  }
  public class PassingThis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Person().eat(new Apple());
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you want to be explained?

Comment: Which line you didn't understand ?

Comment: public void eat(Apple apple) {
Apple peeled = apple.getPeeled();

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this appears to be an introduction to classes for come sort of course. What this program does is enter through the main method:

```
public class PassingThis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Person().eat(new Apple());
    }
}
```

This creates a new instance of the person class, calling this constructor:

```
class Person {
    public void eat(Apple apple) {
        Apple peeled = apple.getPeeled();
        System.out.println("Yummy");
    }
}
```

This constructor requires an instance of the `Apple` class, so it is called by creating a new instance of it (`new Apple()`)

Inside of that constructor, it makes a new instance of the Apple class by calling the `getPeeled()` method.

```
Apple getPeeled() {
    return Peeler.peel(this);
}
```

This creates a new instance of the `Peeler` class which returns the apple. The `Peeler` class returns the now "Peeled" apple to the person class, which then prints "Yummy"

Comment: 1)what is apple.getPeeled()

Comment: apple.getPeeled() returns the result of the method Peel(Apple apple) which does nothing in this, so it basically just returns itself.

Comment: 1)what is pell  2)in this program eat is metod right

Comment: 1)what do you mean by that? are you talking about the method `peel()`? 2) Yes

Comment: All it does is return the instance of Apple that you use to call it with